# how can I get the first key of the second biggest value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, max, key-value

I want to get the first key from the second biggest value given. With this program I can get the first key with the biggest value given, but I don't know how to tell it that I want the second. On the other hand, I have to be able to work with None values and it doesn't pass them, what can I do?

```
def f(x):
    """Return the first ascending KEY ordering of a dictionary
    based on the second biggest value that is given in a dictionary
    biggest value that is given in a dictionary"""

    dict_face = x
    d = max(dict_face, key=dict_face.get)
    print(d)


####
asserts
####
f({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 500}) == 'b'
f({'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 2, 'd': 500}) == 'c'
f({'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': 500}) == None

###
output:
d
d
  File "/Users/[...]/dict_biggest_value.py", line 7, in f
    d = max(dict_face, key=dict_face.get)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Thanks!

Comment: So the output shold be `c, c` and ???

Comment: no, the output should be b, c y none.

Comment: Why do you have 4 things listed? Your question as a whole is unclear. What do the `f(…) == X`s mean?

Comment: are the asserts that the program has to pass

Comment: @CarmenTur Your function prints something but does not return anything (i.e., with a `return` statement).  Therefore all your tests are equivalent to `None == 'b'`, `None == 'c'`, and so on. To perform your comparisons you must replace `print(d)` by `return d`.

Answer (score 0):

What if the max value is repeated?

That being said, one approach could be:

```
values_list = list(dict_face.values())
largest = max(values_list)
values_list.remove(largest)
second_largest = max(values_list)

for k,v in dict_face.items():
  if v == second_largest:
    return k
```

Comment: Are you still using Python 2?

Comment: No...

values_list.remove(largest)
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'remove'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'max' will give you the functionality you want. Additionally I'd think that you have to think about what happens if you only have, say, 1 or 0 values. You can also think about how you want to handle `None`. I'd personally use it as a "negative infinity", that is, the smallest possible value.

I'd think that you can write something like this:

```py
def second_to_max(input):
    # in here, you track both the max value and the next largest value 
    max = None
    s_max = None
    retVal = ''

    for key, val in input.items():
        # check if val is greater than max, 
        # if so assign max to s_max and val to max
        # and key to retVal
        # You'd have special cases for if max and s_max are None,
        # since you can't actually compare None to an integer

    return retVal
```

Answer (score 0):

- List all integer values (removing `None`).
- Then sort values and find nth maximum (ie n = 1 is max value, n = 2
  is second largest, etc).
- Extract first key value corresponding to target max.

```
def f(input_dict, nth_largest_value):
    """Return nth largest value when sorting values in ascending order"""
    
    # get only unique integer values
    dict_values = list(set([x for x in input_dict.values() if type(x) == int])) 
    dict_values = sorted(dict_values) # ascending order
    if len(dict_values) >= nth_largest_value:
        for key in input_dict:
            if input_dict[key] == dict_values[-nth_largest_value]:
                return key
```

Input: `f({'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': 400, 'd': 500}, 2)`

Output: `'c'`